# Apache-Superset not loading new UI components after upgrading

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to upgrade apache-superset from 0.38.0 to 1.0.0. But even though the UI version says it is 1.0.0, I don't see most of the new UI components like filters, advanced search options, and thumbnail views on `Dashboard`, `Charts`, and `Query` views.

I can see the updated UI on my local which I build from source. I even tried creating a wheel file from my local source installed it on the server but sees the same old UI.

Can someone please help me understand the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the new features are behind feature flags. In your config, add:

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
  "THUMBNAILS": True,
  "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS": True,
  "OMNIBAR": True
}
```

Other feature flag options can be found in [config.py](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/4255c22d016027f36e275f9e975672227b7fa9bb/superset/config.py#L293)